# minimize rows with common values, add columns for additional values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have an array, of the following format:

```
564387.29   7371625.14  0.00    33030.00    -132.96 -1031.50

564387.29   7371625.14  0.00    1530.00     -133.85 -1039.27

564387.29   7371625.14  0.00    47970.00    -138.35 -1044.40

564387.32   7371625.14  0.00    47970.00    -166.41 -999.27

564387.32   7371625.14  0.00    33030.00    -241.74 -1889.71

564387.32   7371625.14  0.00    1530.00     -135.42 -857.31

564387.35   7371625.14  0.00    33030.00    -174.06 -990.66

564387.35   7371625.14  0.00    1530.00     -178.17 -927.11

564387.35   7371625.14  0.00    47970.00    -116.65 -1810.97
```

I make the array a pandas dataframe, and sort them based on columns 1, 2 and 4:

```
564387.29   7371625.14  0.00    1530.00     -133.85 -1039.27

564387.29   7371625.14  0.00    33030.00    -132.96 -1031.50

564387.29   7371625.14  0.00    47970.00    -138.35 -1044.40

564387.32   7371625.14  0.00    1530.00     -135.42 -857.31

564387.32   7371625.14  0.00    33030.00    -241.74 -1889.71

564387.32   7371625.14  0.00    47970.00    -166.41 -999.27

564387.35   7371625.14  0.00    1530.00     -178.17 -927.11

564387.35   7371625.14  0.00    33030.00    -174.06 -990.66

564387.35   7371625.14  0.00    47970.00    -116.65 -1810.97
```

the final step is to reduce the number of rows by adding the variable on 4 additional columns to get the following:

```
564387.29   7371625.14  0.00    1530.00 -133.85 -1039.27    -132.96 -1031.50    -138.35 -1044.40

564387.32   7371625.14  0.00    1530.00 -135.42 -857.31     -241.74 -1889.71    -166.41 -999.27

564387.35   7371625.14  0.00    1530.00 -178.17 -927.11     -174.06 -990.66     -116.65 -1810.97
```

but I cannot seem to find a way to - I looked on many numpy and pandas discussion and couldn't get any ideas

Answer (score 2):

1. Sort it according the specific colomns
2. Group them and then apply our customized function

Followings are the example:

```
In [121]: def func(df):
   .....:     df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
   .....:     s = [df.ix[0][3]]
   .....:     for index, rw in df.iterrows():
   .....:         s.append(rw[4])
   .....:         s.append(rw[5])
   .....:     return pd.Series(s)
   .....: 

In [122]: df.sort([0, 1, 3]).reset_index(drop=True).groupby([0, 1, 2]).apply(func)
Out[122]: 
                           0       1        2       3        4       5        6   
0         1          2                                                         
564387.29 7371625.14 0  1530 -133.85 -1039.27 -132.96 -1031.50 -138.35 -1044.40
564387.32 7371625.14 0  1530 -135.42  -857.31 -241.74 -1889.71 -166.41  -999.27
564387.35 7371625.14 0  1530 -178.17  -927.11 -174.06  -990.66 -116.65 -1810.97
```

Answer (score 0):

@waitingkuo thanks, this will produce what I want; I tried to use it with my actual data, that have more rows needed to be converted to columns (total of 7 rows per dataset where as in the examples there were only 3 rows) and now I get this format:

564387.29  7371625.14  0  0     1530.00000

```
                      1     -133.84641

                      2    -1039.27338

                      3     -133.48476

                      4    -1036.76991

                      5     -307.65603

                      6    -1747.01828

                      7     -132.95704

                      8    -1031.49587

                      9     -138.35364

                      10   -1044.39817

                      11    -119.70329

                      12    -981.84015

                      13     -89.65443

                      14    -919.83924
```

...

it looks like everything up to grouping works, and then the rows do not get appended...